# Break line when one single character is left at the end of div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a a simple div, where I call some variable from database with php.

Div has for example 500px and it must stay at this width. And I get something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/32x4m.jpg

You can see the "w" at the end of the line, and since it's called by php, I can't manually put  break line code there. Is there any solution, that will automatically enter br or something, when after the last space in line there is one or two symbols left? I don't care if it is php or jquery or whatever :)

thanks!

Comment: Add {word-wrap:break-word;} to the style of your div..

Comment: @kiran, add it as an answer instead of comment.

Answer (score 0):

Add {word-wrap:break-word;} to the style of your div.